# html-testrail not capturing failed tests in testcafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, testrail

I am using testcafe-reporter-html-testrail plugin with my testcafe project. It's capturing the passed test cases but for failed testcases it's not working. I have not used any custom reporter for testcafe. Please give me some suggestions how to achieve capturing the failed testcases in testrail report?

Comment: You could probably have a look at Agiletestware Pangolin (https://www.agiletestware.com/pangolin) solution which we develop. It supports NUnit format and you can generate it with https://github.com/AndreyBelym/testcafe-reporter-nunit

Comment: The reporter should capture all the tests, either passed or failed. How exactly do you run TestCafe? With CLI or with Test API? What options do you pass to it? Are there any exceptions during run? According to [the plugin's README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-reporter-html-testrail), all your test names should have specific format (like `<< Group Name>> | << Test Name >> | << Testrail Case_ID >> `). Do they?

Comment: @AlexeyLindberg Thank you so much! I was missing that